# Calculate past date using Months value

Tags: c++, datetime

I want to calculate past date from today based on Months input.
Like today is 29-08-2019, 6 months before it was be 29-02-2019.

User inputs would be number of months. It could be 6, 8, 18, 30, 60....
I want to calculate exact complete date. I have tried below code which helps me to get Date for current and past year, but I am looking some solution to get date for months value which is much higher.

```
time_t now = time( NULL);
struct tm now_tm = *localtime( &now);


int inDuration = 0;
std::cout << "Add Duration..." << std::endl;
std::cin >> inDuration; //month value. looking for solution when mnth value is more then month in current and previous year.


int crnMonth = now_tm.tm_mon+1;
int pastDay = now_tm.tm_mday;
int pastMonth = 0;
int pastYear = now_tm.tm_year + 1900;


if(inDuration > crnMonth)
{
    pastMonth = (12-(inDuration-crnMonth));
    pastYear = (now_tm.tm_year + 1900)-1;
}
else
{
    pastMonth = crnMonth-inDuration;
}

printf("%d-%d-%d", pastDay, pastMonth, pastYear);
```

Comment: This is not easy to do, as you have to factor in daylight savings, leap years and leap seconds. Dates and times is *deceptively* easy, but includes so many corner and special cases that it's better to find a library that will do it for you.

Comment: If you dont have to use time_t maybe this can do the job for you. https://thispointer.com/how-to-add-subtract-days-months-or-years-from-a-date-in-c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy using [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    // Get current local date
    auto now_utc = floor<seconds>(system_clock::now());
    auto now_local = zoned_seconds{current_zone(), now_utc}.get_local_time();
    year_month_day crnDate{floor<days>(now_local)};

    // Get number of months
    int inDuration = 0;
    std::cout << "Add Duration..." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> inDuration;

    // Compute past date
    auto pastDate = crnDate - months{inDuration};
    if (!pastDate.ok())
        pastDate = pastDate.year()/pastDate.month()/last;
    std::cout << pastDate << '\n';
}
```

Example output:

```
35
2016-09-29
```

The first few lines get the current time (in UTC), and then convert that to your local time, and then converts the local time to a `{year, month, day}` structure.

Then the number of desired months is obtained from the user as in your question.

Finally, the input is converted to a `months` duration and that is subtracted from the current date.  If the current date is near the end of a month, it is possible that the past date won't be a valid date (e.g. September 31).  If this happens, one has to decide on a policy of what to do.  The above example chooses to "snap" to the end of the month.  Other policies such as overflowing into the next month are also possible.

Some [installation is required for the local time zone support](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).

If getting the current date in UTC is good enough, then no time zone support is required and you could use the header-only library "date/date.h" (requires no installation).  Just `#include "date/date.h"` instead of `#include "date/tz.h"`, and change the first 3 lines to:

```
// Get current UTC date
year_month_day crnDate{floor<days>(system_clock::now())};
```

And the rest of the program works with the same code.

Comment: Thanks Howard. Project setup I have forces me to use time_t. I will mark this as answer, so that it can help others.

Comment: Fwiw, you can convert your input `time_t` into a `system_clock::time_point`.  Then you can convert your output `pastDate` into a `system_clock::time_point`, and then back into a `time_t`.